# jQuery `children` versus ` find`

Tags: jquery

#### HTML

```
<table id='t'>
  <tr>
    <td id='foo' class='a b c'>blah</td>
    <td id='bar' class='a c'>bloo</td>
    <td id='zip' class='a b c'>blop</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Using jQuery, why does the following `children` call return `0`

```
$('#t').children('tr').length
```

but `find` returns 1?

```
$('#t').find('tr').length
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o71x6co6/1/

Comment: Your browser is probably inserting a `<tbody>` element between your `<table>` and your `<tr>` (mine does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because browsers automatically add a `tbody` element if you don't.

```js
console.log($('#t').children().get(0).tagName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='t'>
  <tr>
    <td id='foo' class='a b c'>blah</td>
    <td id='bar' class='a c'>bloo</td>
    <td id='zip' class='a b c'>blop</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```